# drawing an airy func fo harmonic oscsillator in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to draw the airy function of an harmonic oscillator in matlab.
so i know that:

```
V(x)=1/2momega^{2}x^{2}
```

and i know how to solve the integral:

```
int{sqrt{frac{2E}{momega^{2}}}}^{x}sqrt{2m(E-V(x))}dx
```

the resault is: im too lazy to write that function again so from now on we will call it F(x)

```
F(x)= E/omega*arcsin(sqrt{momega^{2}\2E}}x)+E\omega*
*sqrt{1-momega^{2}/2E}x^{2}}+Epi\2omega
```

also, i can tell that the final function (airy function) will look like that:

```
psi = 2c(-1)^{n}\sqrt{2m(E-1\2*momega^{2}x^{2})}}sin(F(x)+pi\4})
```

where c is a const.

I did all that manually, but what i acctually need is to do it all in matlab. I tried to draw it myself but for some reason it gives me a linear function.
the code:(m=1, omega=1, E=0.5*10^6, c=1, n=0)

```
y = @(x) (0.5*10^6).*asin((10^-3).*x);
g = @(x) (0.5*10^6).*sqrt(1-(10^-3).*x);
a = 0.5*pi*0.5*10^6+pi/4;
k = @(x) 2.*sqrt(10^6-x.^2);
f = @(x) y(x)+g(x)+a;
x = -1e-10:-1e-9:-1e-6;
psi = @(x) k(x).*sin(f(x));
plot(x,psi(x))
```

Maybe there's something wrong in my calculations, or in the code itself. Either way i'll appreciate the help! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow the calculation, but the reason you see a linear function is the range of `x` you chose. Try this:

```
ezplot(psi);
```

and you'll see the oscillations.